# Информировать пользователя о том что другой пользователь набирает сообщение (как Вконтакте)

Tags: javascript, php

Добрый вечер! Подскажите, как можно реализовать что бы при наборе символов в поле, у другого пользователя появлялась картинка что первый пользователь набирает сообщения (т.е. как в диалогах Вконтакте).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) На странице сообщение у каждого пользователя делаем скрытый div внутри которого текст + картинку о наборе текста.
2) При наборе символов в поле - вешать обработчик, что были изменения в поле - и отсылать ajax запрос, что юзер производит написание текста.
3) На ответной стороне производить каждое N секунд проверку ajax запросом, были ли изменения какие-либо, принимать и обрабатывать.
4) Если были изменения открываем div блок.

Это самый легкий способ, можно организовать данные вещи на NodeJS + [Socket.io](http://Socket.io)

Comment: ajax реализация запрос == существенные задержки, как в случае получении события набора текста, так и в случае его окончания, к тому-же, такая  реализация (ajax + php) довольно накладная для сервера, особенно учитывая то, что для этого нужно все время напрягать БД

Comment: @AlexWindHope, В зависимости от ресурсов и оптимизации данной "модели изобретения" :) Это, как самый легкий вариант.

Можно сделать на NodeJS + Socket.io - будет все быстро и хорошо :)

Comment: Я намекаю на то, что эта модель, мягко говоря, ущербна.

Кстати - не соглашусь с тем, что она проще, как по мне - очень даже наоборот

Comment: Кому, что ближе по душе - тот на том и работает! :)

Можно было сделать на сокетах в php.

Comment: на сокетах, кстати, даже на PHP, намного лучше с т.з. целесообразности использования серверных ресурсов

Comment: На самом деле, вариаций очень много. Это уже решать автору, главное натолкнуть его на путь истинный!